# Why is the result of this c code "days: 33" and not "days: 30"?

Tags: c, switch-statement, label, break

I'm studying for a test and in an old exam it was asked what the output for the below code was. I'm confused at how this code outputs "days: 33". is there any way to explain it easily?

Edit: Thanks for the explanations, and yes, I know the logic of this code makes no sense (as far as calculating the actual number of days in a given month in a given year), its just an old exam question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calcDays(int, int);

int main(){

    int days;
    
    days = calcDays(11, 2020);
    
    printf("days: %d\n", days);

    return 0;
}

int calcDays(int month, int yr){

    int days = 28;
    
    switch(month)
    {
        case 2:    days += 1 - yr % 4;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:   days += 2;
        default:   days += 3;
    }
    
    return(days);
}
```

Comment: Note that `yr % 4` is a number in the range 0 to 3.

Comment: Your `switch/case` does not have `break`s.

Comment: Hint: `case` falls through. Always `break`!

Comment: Looks like you need to read about the `break` statement

Comment: You also need to read the full rules for leap years in the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: The year 2100 is not a leap year!  Hence, you can't assume `y%4` is the correct way to adjust the number of days in Februrary.  The correct formulae for leap year is `(year% 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the switch statement within the function there is no break statement between these two labels

```
case 11:   days += 2;
default:   days += 3;
```

So these statements

```
days += 2;
days += 3;
```

be evaluated sequantialy.

You could get the expected result if there was a break statement like

```
case 11:   days += 2; break;

default:   days += 3;
```

For example if the parameter month is set to 2 then all these statements

```
days += 1 - yr % 4;
days += 2;
days += 3
```

in this code snippet

```
case 2:    days += 1 - yr % 4;
case 4:
case 6:
case 9:
case 11:   days += 2;
default:   days += 3
```

will be evaluated.

Pay attention to that this statement

```
days += 1 - yr % 4;
```

does not make a sense because a remainder of division by 4 can be either 0, or 1, or 2, or 3.

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` statement is a “calculated jump.” All it does is jump to one of the labels in the attached statement (which is usually a compound statement containing multiple statements with labels) or, if none of the labels match, beyond the attached statement.

So `switch (month)` jumps either to the statement labeled `case 2` or to the statement labeled `case 4`, or the one labeled `case 6`, or the one labeled `case 9`, or the one labeled `case 11` or the one labeled `default`. Then program execution continues normally: It executes the statement that was jumped to, and the statement after that, and the statement after that, and so on.

The labels do not partition the statements into separate sets. Case 2 does not end where the `case 4` label is. After the `case 2` statement is executed, control continues to the `case 4` statement; it does not jump out of the `switch` statement.

So, once the program jumps to the statement `case 11: days += 2;`, it executes `days += 2;`. Then it goes on to the next statement, which is `default: days += 3;`, and executes that.

Note that `default: days += 3;` is a statement, and so is `case 11: days += 2;`. Putting a label in front of any statement makes a new statement:

`days += 2;` is a statement. `case 11: days += 2;` is a statement (that contains another statement, `days += 2;`). `case 9: case 11: days += 2;` is a statement (that contains two other statements). `case 6: case 9: case 11: days += 2;` is a statement, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch does not have break at the end, so everything will be added to days. Try this:

```
switch(month)
{
    case 2:    days += 1 - yr % 4; break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:   days += 2; break;
    default:   days += 3; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent your `case` from falling-through:

```c
int calcDays(int month, int yr){

    int days = 28;
    
    switch(month)
    {
        case 2:
          days += leapOffset(yr);
          break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:  
          days += 2;
          break;
        default:
          days += 3;
    }
    
    return(days);
}
```

An even simpler approach that's harder to foul up:

```c
int calcDays(int month, int yr) {
    switch(month)
    {
        case 2:
          return 28 + leapOffset(yr);
          break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:  
          return 30;
          break;
        default:
          return 31;
    }
    
    return(days);
}
```

Both of these require a valid `leapOffset()` calculation:

```c
int leapOffset(int yr) {
  return ((yr % 4 == 0) && (yr % 100 != 0) || (yr % 400) == 0)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 33 instead of 30 because there is no break in case: 11. You may want to write it as:

```
case 11:   {
    days += 2;
    break;
}
```